Error requiring GLPK.js in React "GLPK is not a function"
I am trying to build a web app that involves solving an integer linear program (basically, I am doing constrained group assignment). In order to solve this ILP, I am trying to use the javascript porting of the GLPK library that is in npm. I installed it by doing npm i glpk.js Then, I imported the package in my function as
const foo = async () => {
     const GLPK = require('glpk.js');
     const glpk = GLPK();
     ...
}

and this gave the error

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: GLPK is not a function

Because of the "(in promise)" part, I also tried to await the require, but this gave the same error.

try import GLPK from "glpk.js"    The "(in promise)"  is because you marked the function async and nothing to do with GLPK.

When I just use import, it seems to load. However, it gives the error that "glpk.solve()" is not a function. When I try to just console.log(glpk), it says that it is a pending promise (Promise {<pending>}).

My guess was that because the glpk.js package uses a webasm file, you need to await the import of the package, which is why I tried to do const GLPK = await require("glpk.js") in an async function.

console.log(await glpk)
